# Remove Value of dependent field

Tags: 7

I've one date field which is dependent on another field if it is checked then only date field will display and will be compulsory. Issue is that if I give value once on date field and saved that page, then I'll edit again same node and uncheck that dependent field value then it will be hide from page but the previous value of that date field is not removed from database. If anyone have an solution to remove this value on remove dependency then let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use any of these modules.

1. [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) - This module definitely solve your issue. [How to use](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5z-GrHvl7s8).

> Conditional Fields allows you to manage sets of dependencies between
>   fields. When a field is “dependent”, it will only be available for
>   editing and displayed if the state of the “dependee” field matches the
>   right condition. When editing a node (or any other entity type that
>   supports fields, like users and categories), the dependent fields are
>   dynamically modified with the States API.

2. [Dependent Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/dependent_fields)

> The Dependent Fields module (formerly AHAH Dependent Fields) allows
>   cck based fields to specify another field as a controller field, and
>   react to its changes on the form using AHAH/AJAX without the form
>   re-loading.

3. [Dynamic dependent fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/ddf)

> Makes field value or options depend on other field values when editing
>   entity.

Comment: Welcome @VirangJethva. I have update answer please check how to use.

Answer (score 1):

Used [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) and attached [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWQTj.png) for the setting up default clear value of dependent field.